# React store promise array of objects in state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6

I need to store the result of a Firestore query in my component state. Below is my code, whenever I try to store the result of the query (which returns an object, or array of objects) in my state, it shows as undefined.

Receiving this error message:

```
 Error getting documents:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
        at index.js:43
        at index.cjs.js:14701
        at index.cjs.js:3357
        at t.pt (index.cjs.js:1200)
        at t.pt (index.cjs.js:1200)
        at t.pt (index.cjs.js:1117)
        at t.forEach (index.cjs.js:3356)
        at t.forEach (index.cjs.js:14699)
        at index.js:41

        const PropertySearch = () => (
            <div>
            <PropertySearchWrapped />
            </div>
        )

        const INITIAL_STATE = {
          postCode: '',
          propertySearched: {},
          propertyList: {},
          error: null,
        };

        class SearchForProperty extends Component {
             constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE };
            }

            onChange = event => {
            this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
            };

            onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var { postCode, error, propertySearched, propertyList} = this.state;
    return this.props.firebase.db.collection("property").where("postcode", "==", postCode)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            this.setState({
                propertyList: doc.data
            })        
            // Need to display this data in a component
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting that error is because you aren't using arrow functions in your in the promise code. The normal functions are likely losing the this reference to your component.

```
    var { postCode, error, propertySearched, propertyList} = this.state;
    return this.props.firebase.db.collection("property").where("postcode", "==", postCode)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot)=> {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            this.setState({
                propertyList: doc.data
            })        
            // Need to display this data in a component
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Although once that's working, you'll probably run into an issue where propertyList is only being set with the last snapShot's data, so You should likely use `querySnapshot.map` instead of forEach so you can add a list of `doc.data` to propertyList instead of a single one.

```
    var { postCode, error, propertySearched, propertyList} = this.state;
    return this.props.firebase.db.collection("property").where("postcode", "==", postCode)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot)=> {
            this.setState({
                propertyList: querySnapshot.map((doc)=> doc.data)
            })        
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same thing, but with a little more explanation of `this`, so I'll just add on to this

Comment: This is actually because of how the `this` context works, which is controlled by the way a function is called. When you supply a callback function to another function, and it is called internally something like this `cb()`, then this actually causes the function's `this` context to refer to the global scope. Because your react code is likely being transpiled to code that uses strict mode, `this` will end up being `undefined`, causing your issue.

What you want to be doing is using arrow functions, because they allow the `this` context to be inherited from its parent functions.

Comment: This is the same reason you will see the pattern `this.func = this.func.bind(this)` in the `constructor` of React components for functions that are passed as handlers or callbacks to things like `onClick` for example (which could also be avoided by using arrow functions)

Comment: Thanks, in particular I didn't know that I lost the this reference, very helpful.